# WebView android does not wrap the text

Tags: android, text, webview

I've searched the Internet for a solution but I can't find it.

I have a WebView that display text, Just text. I want to wrap the text in the WebView, is that possible, or what?

And I want to make the user be able to select a certain text in the WebView and make him able to send the selected text by SMS, is that possible to?

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution.  You have to add some div tag on your web document, and then add a css class. I did this:

```
<div class="wrap">
```

with a css class like this:

```
.wrap {
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: Please note that the OP has a 2-part question.  Do you know an answer for the second part?

Comment: This breaks words in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

If the content in the WebView is something that you yourself have created or have control of, use a stylesheet optimized for mobile devices, or you can use [jTouch](http://jtouch.colorcharge.com/) or [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If your content is literally plain text (no HTML markup), then the WebView will be treating it as preformatted text and won't wrap or insert linebreaks.

Try wrapping your text in an HTML wrapper:

```
<html><body>My text goes here</body></html>
```

Comment: i used TextView before WebView, but i wasn't able to zoom in and out using TextView, So, if you have any idea about zoom text in TextView that will be great.