# how to Scale a webview so that its text content will not wrap?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Currently I'm stuck in a problem with `WebView`. I want to scale the WebView so that its text contents should not wrap on increasing or decreasing the scale factor. For that i tried to use `WebView.setScaleX(value)` and `webview.setScaleY(value)` but what is happening after this is I am not able to scroll the WebView and can not see the complete webpage in the WebView. So I need that whenever the webview scale will increase or decrease  the content become larger or shrink so that the text will not wrap and displayed in bigger/smaller size like we are zooming in or out.

Is anyone of you having any idea that how to sort out this problem?

Comment: What platform are you targeting?

Comment: android 2.3 and later version

Comment: what my problem is when checkbox is selected so i have to wrap the content otherwise not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it will work in this case, but you can usually add `&nbsp` instead of spaces in HTML, they are supposed to keep it from breaking (**N**on **b**reaking **sp**ace)

If that works, you could replace the original using `element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/ /g,'&nbsp');`

Answer (score 1):

Haven't had much experience with this, but according to:

[WebView android does not wrap the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378211/webview-android-problem-does-not-wrap-the-text)

if you have access to the web page content, just wrap it to be not mobile friendly. if you do NOT have access to change the webpage content, try to fetch the URL with a GET request to download it, and then modify the text in there to wrap it with standard HTML wrappings

```
<head>
    <body>
        blah
    </body>
</head>
```

and then feed that text data to your webview object

Comment: anyway thanks for giving answer but sorry i can not accept the answer because this is not what i am looking for but thanks a lot

Comment: no worries :) yeah, only accept answers if they actually solve your problem. half of my questions are answered by me because it's pretty hard to debug someone else's code :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing (not tried it myself), but have you tried calling one of these after setting the scale:

- setScrollContainer
- setScrollBarStyle
- setVerticalScrollBarEnabled
- setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled

It might be that you need to invoke one of these in order to allow scrolling after scaling your view.

Answer (score 1):

you have to css it not to word wrap? that's the only way, it has nothing to do with your web view, well unless its someone else's web page. but if its your web page you have to explicitly put in styles for it not to wrap word

```
 white-space:nowrap;
```

Comment: i am trying to set this property by program but its not working like what i have to do is when checkbox is selected content should wrap otherwise not

Answer (score 0):

it was the problem of lower version some feature do not work well there in android

Comment: Would be nice to add some details for other people.